# Calculating time 90 minutes prior to due date/time in Objective C (iPhone app)

Tags: objective-c, ios4

This is a completely noobish question, but I spent 2 hours yesterday trying to make it work, and I'm obviously missing something very basic.

What I need to do is take input from user of date/time and count back 90 minutes for an alert.

Could someone please post an example calculation, where you have a var that holds user input and a new var that receives the result of this computation? (all done in Objective C for use in an iPhone app) Thank you!

Comment: Asking someone to provide work to you is not going to be as effective as providing specific examples of what you've tried with specific problems. We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: I agree with @Nick. If you've spent two hours on this you surely have some code you could share. Asking us for what you've done wrong is much more effective than asking for a complete example.

Comment: Nick, while I get your sentiment... everything I tried was pure garbage. Having zero formal training in this, I'm looking for style of writing, as much as I'm looking for a code examples that work. This is not for a work purpose. I'll take this criticism into account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
NSDate * alarmDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:5400 sinceDate:userDefinedDate];
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];   
NSTimeInterval wait = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:alarmDate];

[self performSelector:@selector(callAlarm) withObject:nil afterDelay:fabs(wait)];
```

Although I do agree with Nick too, adding your work its much more productive..

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you could do something like:

```
NSDate *alertDate = [userDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-5400.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `UIDatePicker`, your target date will already be in an `NSDate` object. If it's coming from another source, you're probably ending up with it in an NSDate object, either from a string via an `NSDateFormatter` or by some other means.

From an NSDate object, you can get an `NSTimeInterval` relative to some absolute date. That's a C primitive type (it's a `double` in practice, but obviously don't code to depend on that) that you can do arithmetic directly on. So you can subtract 90 minutes directly from that. There are then various `+ dateWithTimeInterval...` class methods on NSDate that will allow you to get a date from the result.